# R: webscraping a table not showing any data

Tags: r

I am trying to webscrape an option table:

http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/base/copper_quotes_settlements_options.html

I tried:

```
library(XML)
options.cu<-readHTMLTable("http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/base/copper_quotes_settlements_options.html",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
options.cu
```

But I just get:

$table_under_bluebar
          V1   V2         V3
1 Trade Date Type Expiration

and no data from the table.
I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table is dynamically created using javascript. You can inspect the traffic to see if you can find a feed. Doing this you will note the following url:

```
http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/xsltTransformer.do?xlstDoc=/XSLT/da/DailySettlement.xsl
```

this takes a url as a parameter which denotes the product line or such. For example:

```
http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/xsltTransformer.do?xlstDoc=/XSLT/da/DailySettlement.xsl&url=/da/DailySettlement/V1/DSReport/ProductCode/HX/FOI/OOF/EXCHANGE/XCEC/Underlying/HG/ProductId/797
```

would get the table for copper options which probably has product id 797. Additional parameters can be added by specifying parameters:

```
http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/xsltTransformer.do?xlstDoc=/XSLT/da/DailySettlement.xsl&url=/da/DailySettlement/V1/DSReport/ProductCode/HX/FOI/OOF/EXCHANGE/XCEC/Underlying/HG/ProductId/797?tradeDate=04/17/2013&monthYear=null&optionTypeName=Daily&optionType=AME
```

You should be able to use this feed to get the relevant data:

```
xmlD <- "http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/xsltTransformer.do?xlstDoc=/XSLT/da/DailySettlement.xsl&url=/da/DailySettlement/V1/DSReport/ProductCode/HX/FOI/OOF/EXCHANGE/XCEC/Underlying/HG/ProductId/797"

library(XML)
options.cu <- readHTMLTable(xmlD,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(options.cu)
#List of 1
# $ DailySettlementTable:'data.frame':  337 obs. of  10 variables:
#  ..$ V1 : chr [1:337] "Daily Settlements for Copper American Options (FINAL)Trade Date: 04/18/2013" "Strike" "025" "050" ...
#  ..$ V2 : chr [1:337] NA "Type" "Call" "Call" ...
#  ..$ V3 : chr [1:337] NA "Open" "-" "-" ...
#  ..$ V4 : chr [1:337] NA "High" "-" "-" ...
#  ..$ V5 : chr [1:337] NA "Low" "-" "-" ...
#  ..$ V6 : chr [1:337] NA "Last" "-" "-" ...
#  ..$ V7 : chr [1:337] NA "Change" "+.0170" "+.0170" ...
#  ..$ V8 : chr [1:337] NA "Settle" "2.9545" "2.7045" ...
#  ..$ V9 : chr [1:337] NA "EstimatedVolume" "-" "-" ...
#  ..$ V10: chr [1:337] NA "Prior DayOpen Interest" "-" "-" ...
```